# Java String to Date Convertion

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to convert a string to date

I tried in couple ways but i'm getting the same.Please could any one help me out.

```
String stringDate ="20181228184821";
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
try {
    date = sdf1.parse(stringDate);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("ICICIBusinessLogic Error in converting input date string ****" + e);
}
```

I get the following exception :

> Error in converting input date string ****java.text.ParseException:
>   Unparseable date: "20181228184821"

Comment: Your format requires a space and two colons.  The value you're trying to parse has none of those.

Comment: Date you are providing is unacceptable format "20181228184821" like 2018-12-28 18:48:21

Comment: Thanks for the response but i'm getting the date String from the service with above mentioned format.

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")

Comment: You mean that both value and format are received ? Then you don't have anything to do. Ask for the correct formatted value based on the format.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

Your stringDate should exactly match your format.

`20181228184821 => 20181228 18:48:21` should work.

Or change your format to `yyyyMMddHHmmss`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong *pattern*, use the following instead :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Also, `SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated, make use of java-8's [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

```
LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You *should* use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and the new classes in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) instead of the old `SimpleDateFormat` api. That being said, you appear to have confused your input and your output formats.

```
String fmtIn = "yyyyMMddHHmmss", fmtOut = "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss";
String stringDate = "20181228184821";
TemporalAccessor dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmtIn).parse(stringDate);
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.from(dt));
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmtOut).format(dt));
```

Comment: Is there any considerable issues of using `SimpleDateFormat` compared to `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: @AtheeshRathnaweera There are too many to mention here. `SimpleDateFormat` is causing a lot of trouble for many programmers, and its fellows like `Date` are poorly designed too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Going through a `TemporalAccessor` is not the recommended way. Just do `LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmtIn));` (and drop the `from` call in the following line). Thanks for showing the use of the modern API.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern specified in Simple Date Format Constructor should be same as the string to be parsed.

Try 
`String stringDate ="20181228 18:48:21";`